# 'FC' is defined but never used.eslint (no-unused-vars)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am getting this warning from eslint:

X is defined but never used for every type imported from react or react-native. An example with `FC` and `ViewProps` (See image below).

Here is my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    "plugin:import/typescript",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }],
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": ["error", {
      "required": {
        "some": ["nesting", "id"]
      }
    }],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": ["error", {
      "required": {
        "some": ["nesting", "id"]
      }
    }],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": [1, {
      "custom": "ignore"
    }],
  },
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the  `React.FC`?

Comment: the warning is referring to your "Card",  you are importing say "FC" hence "Defined" but never used that import in Card so that is why lint is giving that warning, solution is either to remove unnecessary imports or to use them.

Comment: @GursharnSingh I do use ViewProps and FC for typing Card.

const Card: FC<ViewProps> = (props: ViewProps) => {
  const { style } = props;
  return (
    <View {...props} style={[styles.container, style]} />
  );
};

Comment: @keikai React.FC does not give an error. 

What about ViewProps?

Comment: Added a second picture!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved the same issue adding 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended' to 'extends' array in .eslintrc

also, if you'll need it, I have "plugin:react/recommended" and "airbnb" in my extends

Comment: This is the only answer and it works so I will mark it as accepted. Thank you @tjnk24